# What variables does global_variables_initializer() do the initialization?

Tags: python, tensorflow, global-variables

In tensorflow, after I use cell.zero_state() to initialize the cell state and hidden state, I should initialize the global variables or the RNN cell won't run.

However, I wonder how does it globalize(initialize variables range?) and what variables does it globalize(bias? weight? activation function?) ?

[enter link description here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py)

I think the parameters that should initialize is non other than: weight, bias, activation function in each neuron.

What does the global_variables_initializer actually do?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you [create a variable](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cbc658095ae228f2f557af47e4901d552573aa15/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py#L300-L301) in TensorFlow, the framework takes care of adding this variable to a collection of created variables. Think of a list with pointers to variables.
The default collection of such variables is called `GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES`.

The function [`tf.global_variables_initializer`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py#L1555) simply [retrieves](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cbc658095ae228f2f557af47e4901d552573aa15/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py#L1370-L1393) all these variables from the collection and [initializes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/cbc658095ae228f2f557af47e4901d552573aa15/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py#L1555) them.

The [`zero_state`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6f3cc9d368a17646f5838e36be3b1c25bf4534fe/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L166-L176) is not directly creating a variable. It simply returns "all-zero"-tensor of the matching shape to the cell variables.

The range of the initial variable values depends on the variable-initializers.

TO sum up: Each weight, bias, hidden state variable is collected in a special list of created variables and TensorFlow just initializes each of these variables similar to the pseudo-code:

```
foreach v in GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES:
    assign v.value = v.call_initializer()
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! So the use of zero_state is like to save the initial 'state' tensor before get the output state of the RNN cell? 

By the way, if I initialize a weight, bias, hidden state by tf.Variable(), will it automatically import to the list that you said? If yes, when I call global_variable_initialize(), will these variable initialize one more?